# JQuery drag, drop and sort

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table with left and right col. Inside the cols, some small tables (as elements) from PHP loop.
I would like to make possible to drag and drop the elements from left to right cols AND also change the sort inside the col itself. Very hard for me !

Here's my code :
HTML part (left col but the right one is the same)

```
<style>
.deplace{
cursor:move;
}
</style>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td id="leftMenu" valign="top" style="width:180px;height:800px;border:1px solid black">
<?php

while($rowg = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlg)){

echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" 
style="background-color:#CCC;border: 1px solid black;height:100px" 
class="deplace" id="left_'.$rowg['id'].'" modulename="'.modif_nom($rowg['module']).'"     sourceid="'.$rowg['id'].'">

echo '<tr><td" align="center" style="width:100%">'.$rowg['module'].'</td></tr>';

echo '</table>';
}
?>
</td></tr></table>
```

And the JS code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  //

$('#leftMenu').Sortable({
  //revert: true,
  accept: 'deplace',
  axis : 'vertically',

  onchange: function(event, ui) { 
    serial = $.SortSerialize('leftMenu');
    $.ajax ( {
    url : "xhr.php?source=leftMenu",
    type : "get",
    data : serial.hash,
    success: function(data){alert(data);}
    });

  }
});

$('#rightMenu').Sortable({
  //revert: true,
  accept: 'deplace',
  axis : 'vertically',

  onchange: function(event, ui) { 
    serial = $.SortSerialize('rightMenu');
    $.ajax ( {
    url : "xhr.php?source=rightMenu",
    type : "get",
    data : serial.hash,
    success: function(data){alert(data);}
    });

  }
});
//only the functions to move the tables from left to right
$('#rightMenu').draggable({
    revert:false,
    helper:'original',

});

$('#leftMenu').droppable({
    over:function(event, ui){                     
    alert('dropped');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

So, like that, it seems there's a conflict between the functions. If I only let the sortable functions, it's OK but I can't do anything in the receiver col and I would like to send a request to PHP to update a mysql table.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

- `Sortable` is lower-case
- SortSerialize does not exist, I think you mean `sortable("serialize")`
- `$('#rightMenu').draggable` should be changed to `$('#rightMenu').children().draggable` because you want to drag the elements inside the menu

Have a look at the [jQuery UI Sortable doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) too.

Comment: Hello,

No, these things are OK. PLease look at this plugin documentation :


  [LINK]http://interface.eyecon.ro/docs/sort

Comment: @Renaud63: Ok, I didn't get that you are using the Interface library. Can you please clarify in your question what libraries you are using? Is it [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) or [Interface](http://interface.eyecon.ro/) - or both?